# Trigger.io Enabling Parse Causes Build to Fail for iOS

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, trigger.io, parse-platform

Enabling `Parse` in my trigger.io app's config causes the build process to fail at 70%.

This is the last bit of the log:

```
[INFO] [ 60%] TakingInstallLock
[INFO] [ 65%] PreflightingApplication
[INFO] [ 65%] InstallingEmbeddedProfile
[INFO] [ 70%] VerifyingApplication
[ERROR] Failed when running /path/to/forge-workspace/appname/.lib/fruitstrap: ------ Install phase ------
```

Is there something else I need to do to get Parse working?

I saw that it doesn't work with a wildcard provisioning certificat but I'm not using one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your provisioning profile doesn't have push notifications enabled.

See steps 1-3 in the Parse push notification docs: https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. Thank you.